# df.groupby(...).agg(set) produces different result compared to df.groupby(...).agg(lambda x: set(x))

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49535966/what-is-the-pythonic-way-of-collapsing-values-into-a-set-for-multiple-columns-pe) it turned out that `df.groupby(...).agg(set)` and `df.groupby(...).agg(lambda x: set(x))` are producing different results.

Data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
       'user_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3], 
       'class_type': ['Krav Maga', 'Yoga', 'Ju-jitsu', 'Krav Maga', 
                      'Ju-jitsu','Krav Maga', 'Karate'], 
       'instructor': ['Bob', 'Alice','Bob', 'Alice','Alice', 'Alice','Bob']})
```

Demo:

```
In [36]: df.groupby('user_id').agg(lambda x: set(x))
Out[36]:
                    class_type    instructor
user_id
1        {Krav Maga, Ju-jitsu}  {Alice, Bob}
2            {Yoga, Krav Maga}       {Alice}
3           {Ju-jitsu, Karate}         {Bob}
4                  {Krav Maga}       {Alice}

In [37]: df.groupby('user_id').agg(set)
Out[37]:
                                class_type                         instructor
user_id
1        {user_id, class_type, instructor}  {user_id, class_type, instructor}
2        {user_id, class_type, instructor}  {user_id, class_type, instructor}
3        {user_id, class_type, instructor}  {user_id, class_type, instructor}
4        {user_id, class_type, instructor}  {user_id, class_type, instructor}
```

I would expect the same behaviour here - do you know what I am missing?

Comment: Related: [Pandas groupby and make set of items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37572611/pandas-groupby-and-make-set-of-items)

Comment: I think this is because when you pass just `set` this will call the iterable on the object which in this case will be the columns, hence why you get this weird result. When you do this with a `lambda` this will call the set ctor on the series values

Comment: @EdChum, thank you! It looks like it happens the way you have describied it, but i don't get why `set` is applied to `df` instead of a single column...

Comment: @jpp, thank you for the link!

Comment: Give me 10 minutes and I should have a definitive answer, I'm in the middle of stepping through the source code

Comment: @EdChum, sure, take your time... and thank you! :)

Comment: My findings so far: `.agg(set)` ends up calling `pd.core.groupby.NDFrameGroupBy._aggregate_generic`, whereas `.add(lambda x: set(x))` ends up calling `pd.core.groupby._GroupBy._python_agg_general`. Both functions can be called with `set` or `lambda x: set(x)` (i.e. `._aggregate_generic(set)`/`._aggregate_generic(lambda x: set(x))` and `._python_agg_general(set)`/`._python_agg_general(lambda x: set(x))`), and each function produces the same result in both cases, but I haven't found out where/why the decision to call one or another is made.

Comment: I've spent 2 hours looking through `pandas` source code. Frustratingly opaque. Very few comments. I'll award a bounty to an answer which gets to the bottom of this one via the source code.

Comment: I've posted an answer which shows why calling `agg(set)` fails basically this situation isn't handled whilst `list, dict, and tuple` are

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK what is happening here is that `set` isn't being handled as it's not `is_list_like` in `_aggregate`:

```
elif is_list_like(arg) and arg not in compat.string_types:
```

see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/base.py#L535)

this isn't `is_list_like` so it returns `None` up the call chain to end up at this line:

```
results.append(colg.aggregate(a))
```

see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/base.py#L569)

this raises `TypeError` as `TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable`

which then raises:

```
if not len(results):
    raise ValueError("no results")
```

see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/base.py#L595)

so because we have no results we end up calling `_aggregate_generic`:

see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3754)

this then calls:

```
result[name] = self._try_cast(func(data, *args, **kwargs)
```

see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3765)

This then ends up as:

```
(Pdb) n
> c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby.py(3779)_aggregate_generic()
-> return self._wrap_generic_output(result, obj)

(Pdb) result
{1: {'user_id', 'instructor', 'class_type'}, 2: {'user_id', 'instructor', 'class_type'}, 3: {'user_id', 'instructor', 'class_type'}, 4: {'user_id', 'instructor', 'class_type'}}
```

I'm running a slightly different version of pandas but the equivalent source line is https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.22.0/pandas/core/groupby.py#L3779

So essentially because `set` doesn't count as a function or an iterable, it just collapses to calling the ctor on the series iterable which in this case are the columns, you can see the same effect here:

```
In [8]:

df.groupby('user_id').agg(lambda x: print(set(x.columns)))
{'class_type', 'instructor', 'user_id'}
{'class_type', 'instructor', 'user_id'}
{'class_type', 'instructor', 'user_id'}
{'class_type', 'instructor', 'user_id'}
Out[8]: 
        class_type instructor
user_id                      
1             None       None
2             None       None
3             None       None
4             None       None
```

but when you use the `lambda` which is an anonymous function this works as expected.

Comment: @EdChum, bounty coming your way in a couple of days. A few comments in the `pandas` source would have been so helpful. Felt like a little merry-go-round.

Comment: Awesome work. Maybe consider replacing the first five links pointing to `master` with hardcoded tags/commits, so they still make sense in the future. I don't get the `is_aggregator` part, that seems to apply only when `isinstance(arg, dict)`?

Comment: So does this mean it's a bug? Or intended but undocumented behavior?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I think this is a bug it should be posted as an issue on [github](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues)

Comment: @jdehesa at the beginning of that function it tries to establish if it's `is_aggregator `, then when it comes to the main body it then checks if it's a `dict` otherwise it executes the alternate branch. The reason is that the data may need to be coerced to be pandas friendly if the calling func is a `dict`, here it fails on the `is_list_like` in the alternate branch, so this returns `None` and it get's handled higher up but it doesn't really handle it as expected. Also the links point to the current released version, not sure if pointing at master is helpful for future readers

Comment: @EdChum Thanks. What I meant is `is_aggregator` is a lambda which seems to be called only in the `isinstance(arg, dict)`... About the links, the first ones point to master, I was suggesting changing all to current release.

Comment: @jdehesa ah OK, I misunderstood, I think the `is_aggregator` is to handle if the values are of any of those types and if so to preserve ordering by constructing an orderedDict, I'll update my links to `0.22.0`

Comment: @jdehesa I've edited out the first part as it's irrelevant as you've pointed out, I spent an hour stepping through using `pdb` before getting to the juicy bit and then re-pieced the call stack which is why that bit was in the original post of my answer

Comment: @EdChum, can you share how you narrowed down to the exact execution steps? For example, were you using a library or IDE built-in (like VS Step In function for C coding?) that actually showed you which functions it called step by step? I did try to read the source code but there must be a better way.

Comment: @B.Mr.W. I use ipython and pdb nothing fancy

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps as @Edchum commented `agg` applies the python builtin functions considering the groupby object as a mini dataframe, whereas when a defined function is passed it applies it for every column. An example to illustrate this is via print.

```
df.groupby('user_id').agg(print,end='\n\n')

 class_type instructor  user_id
0  Krav Maga        Bob        1
4   Ju-jitsu      Alice        1

  class_type instructor  user_id
1       Yoga      Alice        2
5  Krav Maga      Alice        2

  class_type instructor  user_id
2   Ju-jitsu        Bob        3
6     Karate        Bob        3


df.groupby('user_id').agg(lambda x : print(x,end='\n\n'))

0    Krav Maga
4     Ju-jitsu
Name: class_type, dtype: object

1         Yoga
5    Krav Maga
Name: class_type, dtype: object

2    Ju-jitsu
6      Karate
Name: class_type, dtype: object

3    Krav Maga
Name: class_type, dtype: object

...
```

Hope this is the reason why applying set gave the result like the one mentioned above.

Comment: Thank you! Your demonstration is very clear! I will wait bit more for alternative answers and will accept the best one. You already have my vote for this answer ;-)

Comment: Haha @MaxU I'm more curious. I couldn't grasp the source code much. Someone might comeup with more efficient answer :)